# Inner sub sub menus is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using collapse list unstyled class for showing submenus.In that sub sub menus are not showing, only first submenu is displaying but not the second one.

```
<li>
                    <a href="#icdSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>&nbsp;
                        ICD
                    </a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="icdSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#setup1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-server" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Maintenance</a>
                            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="setup1">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;IC Profile</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Product Master</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Supplier Master</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="icdSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#setup2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-server" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Maintenance1</a>
                            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="setup2">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;IC Profile1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Product Master1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Supplier Master1</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</li>
```

In the above code only "Maintenance" menu is displaying but "Maintenance1" menu is not displaying..
Did I missed any syntax..

I have included my CSS part below...

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 183px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #3c3c47;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3,
#sidebar.active .CTAs {
    display: none;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    text-align: left;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a i {
    margin-right: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active .dropdown-toggle::after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 2px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
.add1 {
    background: #dedede;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -11px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {background: none!important;}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;*/
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #1abc9c !important;
}

#sidebar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #1abc9c;
    background: #171d1f;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Hi please include your CSS as well.

Comment: @John I have included my CSS part as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you include jQuery with bootstrap. You can add everything by adding this to your html:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here's your code with no changes, only those libraries added:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<li>
                    <a href="#icdSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>&nbsp;
                        ICD
                    </a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="icdSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#setup1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-server" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Maintenance</a>
                            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="setup1">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;IC Profile</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Product Master</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Supplier Master</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="icdSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#setup2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-server" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Maintenance1</a>
                            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="setup2">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;IC Profile1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Product Master1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Supplier Master1</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks @John...it works likes charm....after including jQuery with Bootstrap